# Free floating car sharing in Prague for travelers

Tags: car-rentals, prague

I will go to Prague. I am looking, just in case I may need that, for a car sharing service like car2go, the same you find in Berlin, Wien and Rome.

I have tried to google for some, but didn't get satisfying info. Since I will be on vacation for a few days I require my car sharing service:

- To run entirely from phone. I can subscribe with my cc and even send them a photo of my European driver's license, but I won't be likely interested in getting a pay-once member card at a fixed place
- To be free floating. It will be an alternative to taxi, so I want to search for a car from wherever I am
- To speak English. Car4way looks like speaking Czech only
- To allow foreigners. It actually took a lot of time for some of my local car sharing services to allow foreign drivers, but eventually now they do

What are car sharing options in Prague?

Comment: Why do you think you might need a car? Why isn't public transport sufficient?

Comment: I'll second that. If you go only to Prague, you certainly don't want or need a car. I drove there a month ago, the experience is disappointing - traffic jams, difficult navigation and expensive parking. Public transport and Uber is way better.

Comment: @GeorgeY depends a lot on what OP wants to visit and at what time of the day/week. Driving on the weekend to sights outside the city (e.g. Kutna Hora) is much more pleasant than public transport.

Comment: Yeah, if you go outside Prague and want to see Karlovy Vary and Ceske Krumlov the same day, then the car is a must. But inside Prague? No way.

Comment: Or if you get lost in the city at 3am and won't dare ever call a taxi for political believings.......... :) I asked the entire question as an additional mobility option

Comment: I'm just curious - does your local car sharing let foreigners register online without paying any sort of deposit? If so, which company is it?

Comment: They do. It is car2go. They require a credit card and online id verification from the app. Credit card is considered sufficient guarantee.

Comment: Also no other car sharing service in my country requires a deposit. But few allow foreign drivers, that's for sure

Comment: We don't need a special car sharing tag currently. The car-rental one is sufficient.

Comment: Sure? Well, there is kind of strong difference between classic car rental (where you book, pick up and retrieve a car at an agency), rather than car sharing where you can locate a car by smartphone and unlock it by phone or member card. Car rentals are good for longer use or longer distances, car sharing is mainly made for in-city moving instead of using public transport (e.g. when you do plenties of shopping or during strikes). In *my* view, they are different services. But *we* are a community and share lots of views

Answer (score 11):

I'm an active Car4Way user and I can tell you with 100% confidence the service you're interested in does not exist as of 2017. Car4Way comes closest to what you need - the cars are free floating, they speak English and they allow foreigners. However registration can only be done with a visit to their office and being a foreigner you would have to leave a 5000CZK deposit.

Use Uber, [Liftago](https://www.liftago.com/invite/MICHAL1586) (the local Uber competitor) or public transportation instead. Another option is to rent a car from a traditional car rental agency, which should also be cheaper than Car4Way if you need it for at least one day.

Comment: Or hire a car for the day. If you go from place to place cross-country it will be much cheaper than a taxi (no matter if Liftago, Uber or traditional).